# Phone got hung while shooting a video- How to get the mp4 file from the ".mp4.tmp0" file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding

Title says it all, I was shooting a video and suddenly the phone got hung. I waited a few minutes with no avail, then had to reboot the phone. I then went to the *Camera* folder, and saw a file with the extension "*mp4.tmp0*". I tried renaming the extension from "*mp4.tmp0*" to "*.mp4*" but it didn't play.

**So, what can I do to make it playable?**

P.S. My phone is a Xiaomi device with Android 9.

Comment: change the file extension from .mp4.tmp0  to .mp4, see if it will play. You may have to copy the file into Windows to change the file extension.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Because the file was not properly closed (the system hung and was shut down) the file is gone.  There is not likely any chance to recover it.

Comment: Is there any way i can get the file, like re-encoding it or something?

Comment: No . The file is gone because of the shutdown